# Спряжение глаголов с ударными личными окончаниями

Tags: грамматика

Как объяснить иностранцам и всем тем, кто со слуху не различает ударные личные окончания глаголов, в каких случаях глагольное личное окончание ударное? Есть ли какие-нибудь способы?

Comment: Пытаюсь понять, в чём, собственно, проблема. Если в неопределённой форме окончание под ударением, то и в личной тоже, нет?  "Грем***е***ть" - "грем***и***т", "звенеть"-"звенит", и т.д.

Comment: Есть, наверное, и другие правила (или можно попробовать придумать для облегчения жизни иностранцев)...

Comment: То есть, это - не правило, да?

Comment: Спряжение глаголов по инфинитиву справедливо только для глаголов с безударными личными окончаниями. У глаголов,у которых личное окончание ударное, спряжение  определяется на слух по окончанию.

Comment: Может быть, пример какой-нибудь приведёте (в вопросе), а то я так и не понял, ***что*** Вы им пытаетесть разъяснить.  Спряжений два, да?  Плюс исключения (вертеть, обидеть, недавидеть, ждать и проч.).  От спряжения зависит как меняется форма по лицам, родам, числу, так ведь?  И что надо объяснить?  Как от конкретной формы получить неопределённую?

Comment: Виктор, для глаголов, у которых безударное,  спряжение определяется по окончанию инфинитива ( неличная форма глагола). Напр.: глаголы у которых в инфинитиве окончание ***еть, -ать, -оть, -уть, -ять, -ыть, -ть***, относятся к первому спряжению. Глаголы, оканчивающиеся на -ить  - к второму спряжению. У этих глаголов личное окончание безударное: зн***а***ешь, зн***а***ет. Чтобы правильно написать окончание, надо знать, к какому спряжению относятся эти глаголы. Но: по***е***шь. Личное окончание ударное, здесь мы знаем, что это глагол первого спряжения. Именно о таких глаголах идет речь.

Comment: Кажется, начинаю понимать.  Тут порочный круг.  Чтобы знать, как писать безударное окончание, надо знать спряжение.  Чтобы знать спряжение, надо выяснить неопределённую форму. Чтобы выяснить неопределённую форму, нужно (если есть) правило, связывающее написание неопределённой формы с личной.  Вы это правило и пытаетесь найти?  Похоже, что его нет.

Comment: Виктор, вы опять не поняли. С безударными окончаниями проблем нет. Оно узнается по неопределенной форме глагола. Меня интересует другой вопрос: как объяснить иностранцам, в каких словах окончание ударное.

Comment: А, ну, это уж точно - дело заучивания, запоминания (т.е. словарное свойство). В русском, кажется, единственное правило ударения - это про букву "ё", и то только в незаимствованных словах...

Comment: Присоединяюсь к Victor Bazarov - только запоминать с помощью постоянной практики, то есть слушать нативных носителей языка, пытаться повторять и говорить. Правила, если они и есть, слишком многочисленны и запутанны, их сложнее запомнить и применять, чем запомнить сами глаголы.

Comment: никак - только запоминать. Правил нет. Полякам в этом смысле легче)

Answer (score 1):

Окончание ударно, когда на него падает ударение. Боюсь, схема ударений окончаний - это словарное свойство глагола. Глаголы на -аю, -ею обычно имеют безударные окончания, но не более того, да и их инфинитивы совпадают с инфинитивами глаголов вроде "писать", "петь".

Было бы удобно предложить иностранцам пользоваться для определения этого "Грамматическим словарём русского языка" А. А. Зализняка.

Comment: Viridianus, окончания -аю, -ею  - это личные окончания. Чтобы написать личное окончание, надо знать спряжение. Когда мы сомневаемся, какое окончание написать: ешь или ишь, мы узнаем, к какому спряжению относится глагол и выбираем правильное окончание. Но есть окончания ударные. В этом случае  мы узнаем спряжение не по инфинитиву, а по личному окончанию. Так вот, как объяснить иностранцем, в каких словах окончание ударное? Я не согласен, что окончание - словарное свойство. Словарь Зализника трудный не только для иностранцев, но и для неподготовленного носителя языка.

Comment: Окончание, может быть, и не словарное свойство, а зависит от спряжения.  Тогда спряжение - словарное.  Не может быть, чтобы спряжение определялось по окончанию, а окончание - по спряжению.

Comment: Окончание узнается по неопределенной форме глагола только у тех глаголов, у которых окончание безударное. Если окончание ударное, то и вопросов не возникает, к какому именно спряжению относится глагол.

Comment: @Серж, читайте внимательнее. Словарное свойство - не окончание, а схема ударения.